# How to access, delete and edit contents in an Array using MongoDB and Express

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I would really like some help with this problem, I am sorta stuck. I am trying to manipulate this UserSchema. I want to be able to edit and delete the shippings array within the model but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to access individual items in the array to use an express restAPI. Below is a snippet of the schema and the restAPI endpoint for creating multiple shipping addresses I was able to write. The create endpoint is working but for some reason I am unable to wrap my head around updating and deleting. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
firstname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
lastname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
},
shippings: [{
    recipient: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    street: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
}],



exports.postShipping = function(req, res, next) {
req.assert('recipient', 'Recipient cannot be blank').notEmpty();
req.assert('street', 'Street Address cannot be blank').notEmpty();
req.assert('city', 'City cannot be blank').notEmpty();
req.assert('state', 'State cannot be blank').notEmpty();
req.assert('zip', 'Zip Code cannot be blank').notEmpty();
// req.assert('country', 'Country cannot be blank').notEmpty();

User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    var shipping = {};
    shipping.street = req.body.street;
    shipping.recipient = req.body.recipient;
    // shipping.unit = req.body.unit;
    shipping.city = req.body.city;
    shipping.state = req.body.state;
    shipping.zip = req.body.zip;
    // shipping.country = req.body.country;
    var s = JSON.stringify(shipping);
    console.log(s);
    var duplicatedShipping = 0;
    for (var i in user.shippings) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user.shippings[i]));
        if (JSON.stringify(user.shippings[i]) == s) {
            duplicatedShipping = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (duplicatedShipping === 0) {
        user.shippings.push(shipping);
    }
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(user.shippings);
        req.flash('success', {
            msg: 'Shipping Address Added'
        });
        res.redirect('/account/me/shipping');
    });

});
```

Comment: What is proper error you are facing, when you are update data?

Comment: I don't have any error when updating because I am not sure how to get the data...I'm trying to figure out how to approach because calling req.user.id gets the id of the user from the URL but how do I access the correct user and also access the correct shipping address associated to that user?